# With a rule's prerequisite both a file and another rule, is only the file date checked, or always first that "sub rule" itself?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Considering the general rule form:

```
output_file_name: dep_file_name1, dep_file_name_2, ..., dep_file_name_n
    recipe
```

and assuming in one's hypothetical `makefile` with no phony targets ever, **every** `dep_file_name_x` is **always** a file name and **often** also another rule (ie. it is another rule's `output_file_name`), my question is:

Hitting any of many such rules, does `make` **only** check the file-mod-time of the `dep_file_name_x` *file* (if it exists of course) or does `make` **also** recognize that `dep_file_name_x` is **also** a another rule in the same `makefile` — which, if "run" (but maybe hasn't *yet*), *would* update the *actual file*?

More briefly: if the `dep_file_name_x` refers to an existing rule **and** an existing file, is it guaranteed the rule is invoked (with its own prereq checks etc) *before* the usual file-mod-time checking?

Comment: Note: I searched & browsed but couldn't find anything _exact_ on this specific question in the `make` docs, and I'm not used to the `makefile` format in general practice. (Newcomer to C++ here actually, really — alt-build-systems and makefile-gens are out for now, thanks =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make works recursively.  Every prerequisite is treated as a target and goes through the entire process of bringing that target up to date.  It doesn't matter if there's a file on the disk for that target or not (except insofar as how it effects make's decision on whether to update it).  It doesn't even matter if there's a rule for the target or not (if not make will try to match an implicit rule).

But yes, if I understand your question correctly, make will always completely attempt to rebuild all prerequisites and wait for them to complete, before checking timestamps to see if the current target needs to be updated.